# About different keywords reserved for font-size like small, large, etc.

Tags: css

The reserved keywords small, large, xx-small, xx-large, etc. are they absolute or relative? (Are they acoording to the size of the device or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are relative and not absolute like px. For more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size